# WIreless connects but Internet stops working on Ubuntu 12.04 64 Bit and Broadcom 4313

Tags: 12.04, wireless, broadcom, dns, realtek

I'm running Ubuntu 12.04 64 Bit on a HP Pavilion dm4. It has a Broadcom 4313 Wireless Adapter and a Realtek RTL8168D/8111D Ethernet Adapter.

I haven't been able to get consistent internet access from either the wireless or wired connection. On startup, or after restarting the router, I am able to load a couple of websites, but after that the internet stops working (though the wirless/ethernet continue to indicate that they are connected). Strangely, I am still able to do things with the websites I have already loaded - for example, loading/sending messages in gmail. It's just loading certain new websites that is the issue. Also, I still see available wireless networks.

This the relevant output from `lspci -v`:

```
02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168B PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet controller (rev 03)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 1469
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 42
    I/O ports at 2000 [size=256]
    Memory at c0404000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Memory at c0400000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: r8168
    Kernel modules: r8168

03:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM4313 802.11b/g/n Wireless LAN Controller (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 145c
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 17
    Memory at c2400000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: wl
    Kernel modules: wl, bcma, brcmsmac
```

I've tried blacklisting the different wireless drivers, but nothing seems to work, even if I try to force it to use the brcmsmac driver, which I've read elsewhere should be the correct one. For the ethernet, I also tried installing the latest driver (r8168 instead of r8169) and blacklisting the old one.

I'm dual booting windows 7 on the same laptop, but have no issues with either the wireless or ethernet connections.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem apears to be with the network stack and not with the drivers.

Most problems I had were with name resolution try pinging a known site to check if name resolves ok.

Comment: with ethernet, pinging works briefly and then stops working while gmail continues to function. This time wireless didn't appear to work at all; it connected to the network but pinging returned nothing.

Comment: try running ifconfig to see if you are getting errors:           RX packets:24699 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
TX packets:20649 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0

Comment: not getting any errors. it does seem to be a dns problem... I'm wondering if it's related to this: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager/+bug/989900

Comment: from that bug report page I got this link, read the part on dnsmasq: http://akyl.net/changes-dns-resolvconf-ubuntu-1204-precise-pangolin

Comment: from that page, this is what solved it:

"To turn off dnsmasq in Network Manager, you need to edit /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf and comment the “dns=dnsmasq” line then do a “sudo restart network-manager”."

Comment: the wireless still doesn't work, but I'm pretty sure that's a driver issues (seems to be quite common), and having domain name resolution working (as well access to the internet under ubuntu =D) definitely helps

Answer (score 2):

Did you try setting **ipv6 to link-local only**? My problem was almost identical to the one you described and after I did this, the difference is like night and day.

**rtl8192ce** driven RTL8188 Realtek wifi card

**Broadcom** driven wireless router

**Ubuntu-Gnome 13.04**

I **ONLY** run on **n**. (I paid for the latest technology and I want to use it.)

Again . . . **IPV6 to Local-Link Only**. Go to **Network Manager** and edit the profile of the network you are connected to and you will find a setting for IPV6.

My ISP **does not** even **offer IPV6** so it took me a while to figure this out. Before, I tried to disable it thinking it was useless and not needed.
I'll see how long my connection lasts, however, I was only receiving 2 out of 5 pings to my router before and now I get 5 out of 5 returned in full. Also, Google searches are lightning fast . . . no more clocking for 3-5 minutes.
Hope this helps! Good Luck

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. After trying almost every possible solution posted in different wikis, I've figured it out in this way: try to set the channel of the wireless in your router under 12 (I've set on 11). The wl driver for broadcom 4313 works only under this channel. I hope it works for you too.

Answer (score 0):

Hooray I fixed it.
Setting it IPV6 to Local-Link Only did the trick.
It is odd though that everything was going fine until about 2 days ago.

Comment: This is a duplicate of mchid's [answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/308051/540008)