# Ubuntu 15.04 internet only works for a few minutes after boot

Tags: wireless, 15.04

I recently purchased a Toshiba satellite L15W-B1208D two in one laptop/tablet. The first thing I did was to wipe websites and install Ubuntu 14.04, as that was the distro I was used to. With 14.04 installed I could only use the internet for about 5-10 minutes after booting the machine. After that it would still say it was connected to Wi-Fi but I could not use the internet to do anything. Browsers would time out, curl would not work, the software center couldn't download packages, etc. I spent days reading forums and trying everything that was suggested in previous posts. Finally I found a post saying an upgrade to 15.04 could help, so I tried it. The internet seems to last a little longer but eventually it disappears and the only way to reconnect is rebooting.

Please do not mark this as off topic because it can't be reproduced; it happens every time I boot on any different Wi-Fi network.

I apologize for the long post, I'm a first time poster and wanted to be detailed. Let me know if there are any commands I could run and post the output of to help diagnose.

Additional info: the machine has no Ethernet connection and has a Realtek RTL8723BE network driver, currently running 15.04 as the only OS.

Thanks in advance!

Edit: Thanks for the quick reply Jeremy!

On 14.04 I first tried the basics like resetting the router and restarting network-manager from the command line. After that I tried live booting from a usb stick to see if the problem persisted, which it did. Then I tried changing the IPv6 settings to "link local only" as suggested here: [WIreless connects but Internet stops working on Ubuntu 12.04 64 Bit and Broadcom 4313](https://askubuntu.com/questions/150933/wireless-connects-but-internet-stops-working-on-ubuntu-12-04-64-bit-and-broadcom). Then I tried

`sudo dhclient wlan0`

as suggested here: [Internet stops working after a few minutes (13.04)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/307361/internet-stops-working-after-a-few-minutes-13-04).
Then I tried

`sudo apt-get remove network-manager`

and reinstalling it from a flash drive. Next I tried this block of code:

`sudo modprobe ath5k nohwcrypt
sudo sh -c "echo 'options ath5k nohwcrypt' >/etc/modprobe.d/custom-wireless.conf"
sudo apt-get remove libnss-mdns`

as suggested by this post: [Internet stops working after some time](https://askubuntu.com/questions/445817/internet-stops-working-after-some-time)
The last thing I tried before switching to 15.04 was to uninstall and reinstall every package I could think of. I'm not sure how to reinstall my network driver so I haven't done so yet. I haven't retried any of these methods since wiping the disk and installing 15.04.

Comment: Please [edit](http://askubuntu.com/posts/687483/edit) your post to include the fixes you have tried

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have the rtl8723be, the first thing I would try is

```
echo "options rtl8723be fwlps=N" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723be.conf
```

Reboot, this parameter of the kernel module disables power management which is known to cause issues with the Realtek wifi cards.

Comment: You've fixed it in one try. I pinged google all night and downloaded matlab overnight with no interruption. I will mark your answer as correct. Many thanks!